# SQLite date "is greater than other date" e.g. '25/09/2014' doesn't work

Tags: sqlite, date

I've a problem with SQLite, and specially with my date.
If I execute the following query :

```
SELECT g.Date FROM game w where g.date = "26/09/2014" order by timestamp desc
```

will give me

- 26/09/2014
- 26/09/2014
- 26/09/2014

But when I change the query item ***=*** into ***>*** and the date into ***"25/09/2014"***

```
SELECT distinct g.Date FROM gamew where g.date > "25/09/2014" order by timestamp desc
```

will give me the following results    *( i've added - distinct)*

- 26/09/2014
- 31/08/2014
- 30/08/2014
- 29/08/2014
- 28/08/2014
- 27/08/2014
- 26/08/2014
- 31/07/2014
- ...

Which aren't the expecting results :( because, only the day is correct.
also
I really don't like to change the database, Date item. I rather like to have a correct query that gave me the correct datums back

**example database**

```
ID - Country - League - Team - Opponent - Location - Result - Scored - Against - Time - Date
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
"20868","Spa","PRD","Celta_de_Vigo","Elche","A","1","1","0","1411758000","26/09/2014"
"47133","Ger","BUN","Hoffenheim","Mainz_05","A","x","0","0","1411756200","26/09/2014"
"59149","Ger","BUN","Mainz_05","Hoffenheim","H","x","0","0","1411756200","26/09/2014"
"25373","Spa","PRD","Cordoba","Valencia"   ,"A","0","0","3","1411675200","25/09/2014" 
 ... 11655 rows ...
```

---

**Edit**
Type of g.Date:

```
DATE       DATE
```

Comment: SQLite doesn't have a `date` data type, so it compares strings. And when comparing strings, `30/08/2014` **is** bigger than `25/09/2014`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DD/MM/YYYY is not a valid SQLite date.

SQLite doesn't have an actual date type and will allow you to store them as TEXT, INT, or REAL.  If you choose TEXT you *must* use the format YYYY-MM-DD which can be recognized by SQLite's date functions and, in any event, will solve your sorting and searching problems.